# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.get(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Ob

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven-plugin, dispatcher, nosuchmethoderror

I get a mistake 500, when i try to edit, add or delete passenger by ID in the table:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u5wX.png)

Here is a mistake

> `here`org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)`

```
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.getById(Unknown Source)
>   com.javaschool.ev.controller.PassengerController.editPassenger(PassengerController.java:57)
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
> logs.
> 
> Apache Tomcat/9.0.45
```

I can edit passenger only when I enter ID myself.

Here is my jsp:

```
</head>
<body>
<h2>SBB Passengers</h2>
<h2><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editPassenger">Edit or Add Passenger</a> </h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Passenger ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Birth Date</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="passenger" items="${passengerList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${passenger.passengerID}</td>
            <td>${passenger.firstName}</td>
            <td>${passenger.lastName}</td>
            <td>${passenger.birthDate}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="editPassenger/${passenger.passengerID}">Edit</a>
                <a href="deletePassenger/${passenger.passengerID}">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<c:url value="/editPassenger" var="add"/>
<a href="${add}">Add new Passenger</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a controller

```
@Controller
public class PassengerController {

/*
add service to call its methods later
@Autowired annotation not to create new objects of the class
 */
private PassengerService passengerService;
@Autowired
public void setPassengerService (PassengerService passengerService){
    this.passengerService=passengerService;
}

/*
all passengers list in a table
value="/" is added again to work later with redirect
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView allPassengers() {
    List<Passenger> passengers = passengerService.allPassengers();
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("passengers");
    modelAndView.addObject("passengerList", passengers);
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
 get to the EditPassenger without ID
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/editPassenger", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editPassenger() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("editPassenger");
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
get to the EditPassenger Page with ID
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/editPassenger/{passengerID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editPassenger(@PathVariable("passengerID") int passengerID) {
    Passenger passenger = passengerService.getById(passengerID);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("editPassenger");
    modelAndView.addObject("passenger", passenger);
    modelAndView.addObject("passenger", passengerService.getById(passengerID));
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
edit passenger method
with POST the data is transferred
"redirect:/" is for redirectinf to the "/" address
*/
@RequestMapping(value = "/editPassenger", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView editPassengerPage(@ModelAttribute("passenger") Passenger passenger) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
    passengerService.edit(passenger);
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
method to get to the page "add new passenger"
jsp looks same as edit --> one jsp for editing and adding the passenger
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addPassenger() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("editPassenger");
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
method of adding passenger
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addPassenger(@ModelAttribute("passenger") Passenger passenger) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
    passengerService.add(passenger);
    return modelAndView;
}

/*
delete passenger from the list
"/" at the beginning is deleted
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/deletePassenger/{passengerID}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deletePassenger(@PathVariable("passengerID") int passengerID) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/");
    Passenger passenger = passengerService.getById(passengerID);
    passengerService.delete(passenger);
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

Here is a pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>SBB</groupId>
  <artifactId>SBB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>



<name>SBB Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springversion>5.3.6</springversion>
  </properties>
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.20</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${springversion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>${springversion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${springversion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${springversion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${springversion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0.Alpha7</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.24</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>9.0.10</version>
</dependency>



 </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SBB</finalName>
        <plugins>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>11</source>
      <target>11</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

And here is a Hibernate COnfig:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.javaschool.ev")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db.properties")
public class HibernateConfig {
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.javaschool.ev.domain");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate version against which some of your code is compiled does not match the Hibernate version at runtime or you have multiple conflicting version of Hibernate on your class path.